# Multiple view on result view

Tags: bixby

Currently able to play audio on a result view. And i wish to reach where the view will differ from audio to audio. And I start from the basic which is display the title of the audio.

```
match{
    Result{
      from-output: playNews{
        from-input: audio.AudioInfo(this){
          from-output: buildNewsAudioInfo{
            from-input: newsAudio{
              from-output: getNews{
                from-input: userWantToHear(whatuserwant)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
render{
    list-of (this){

      where-each (audio){
        title-area{
          slot2{
            paragraph{
              style(Title_XS)
              value("#{value(this.audioItem.title)}")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But this only show a single title for the whole result view.  Is it able to show different view from audio to audio?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "from audio to audio"? I take it to mean that you have a list of multiple audio files and you would like a different view shown for each of these files. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the view for each audio file, you would need to have conditionals that sort through the audio files contained in the `Result` object within the `where-each` block. This will allow you to define different layouts for whatever `if` statements you choose to define.

Adding code to address your comment to this original answer.

```
result-view {
    match {
        YourAudioResult (this)
    }

    render {
        if ("size(this) > 1") {
            list-of (this) {
                where-each (audioItem) {
                    //CONDITIONALS FOR DECIDING HOW EACH ITEM IS SHOWN IN THE LIST VIEW
                }
            }
        } else-if ("size(this) == 1") {
                // CONDITIONALS FOR DECIDING HOW EACH ITEM IS SHOWN IN DETAIL VIEW
    }
}
```

This one view will allow you to define the layouts of audio items when the result has multiple items and when there is a single item.

Comment: Is it possible to use navigation mode, `read-many-and-next` to achieve this result? Defining each audio in a single audio file as one page, and go to next page for the next audio. Wish to achieve where it will display different page of detail for each audio.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example view with pseudo code showing where you can define the conditionals. Hope it helps!

Comment: i think i figure out how should i develop my view now, thanks!